# Is it possible declare optimize for a single package?

Tags: optimization, common-lisp

I am working on a project where I am happy with the vector package and wish to optimize it as much a possible without affecting the other packages that make up the project.
I am aware that I can use the following inside a defun to optimize that single function

```
(declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
```

and also that 'declaim' could be used to make the effect global.

Is there a way to optimize everything in a package or is it just safer to declare in each function?

[EDIT]
Just a heads up to future readers: In almost all cases you do not want to use safety 0. Research this topic further before ever setting this in your code as you are opening yourself up to very system & implementation dependent bugs if you muck it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extent of [declaim](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_declai.htm) is implementation dependent.  In SBCL I think you may use [with-compilation-unit](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Compiler-Policy) to achieve what you want.  However, I doubt the utility of this for performance purpose: most of the time performance critical code is concentrated on a very few places, and whatever gain you may have from the rest of the code is not worth the sacrifices of safety and debuggability.

Comment: Cheers! I will go for the more granular control, but nice to know about this construct.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [LOCALLY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_locall.htm) around one or more forms.

Comment: Thanks, this also solves the problem perfectly. No way accept both answers but at least I can upvote this one as well.